# Nokogiri traverse in opposite direction from node (each parent)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to traverse from a nokogiri node back up through the tree. How can I do that?

It would like to do something like:

```
node.parents do |parent|
 break if parent.attributes['id'].present?
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [`ancestors` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNode%3Aancestors):

```
node.ancestors.each do |a|
  break if a.attributes['id'].present?
end
```

It’s not clear what you’re trying to do, but you can pass a selector as an argument, so to find all ancestors which have an `id` attribute you could do this:

```
node.ancestors("[@id]")
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach to get an array containing all nodes up to the root:

```
get = proc { |n| [n] + (n.respond_to?(:parent) ? get.(n.parent): []) }
get.(node)
```